# Checking Multiple $_GET variables if equals a string

Tags: php

```
  if(isset($_GET['a']) || isset($_GET['b']) || isset($_GET['c'])){
      if(($_GET['a'] || $_GET['b'] || $_GET['c']) == "x"){
          echo "YES";
      } else {
          echo "NO";
      }
  }
```

in this php code, i'm trying to check if one of those requests `isset` and if one of them value `== 'x'` or not, But the 2nd part `if(($_GET['a'] || $_GET['b'] || $_GET['c']) == "x")` doesn't work as intended at all, I wrapped it inside `()` hoping it would work, In this condition, do i have to separate it as i did inthe `isset()` part? or is there a better method to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely what you are looking for

**UPDATE** - I just changed `||` to `&&` for the last condition in case you were quick to try it out.

```
if( (isset($_GET['a']) && $_GET['a'] == "x") || (isset($_GET['b']) && $_GET['b'] == "x") || (isset($_GET['c']) && $_GET['c'] == "x")){
      echo "YES";
} else {
      echo "NO";
}
```

Comment: so this wrapping part `($_GET['a'] || $_GET['b'] || $_GET['c']) == "x"` doesn't work as a collector for all variables as condition?

Comment: `($_GET['a'] || $_GET['b'] || $_GET['c'])` is saying: `$_GET['a']` is `TRUE` or `$_GET['b']` is `TRUE` or `$_GET['c']` is TRUE. After evaluating this, you will have either `TRUE` if one of these is `TRUE` or `FALSE` if not. Then it compares whether this `TRUE` or `FALSE` value is equal to `x`. This is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to write a lot of conditionals you could use one of the following:

Using a foreach and a conditional:

```
$either_abc_is_x = function() {
    $keys = ['a','b','c'];
    foreach($keys as $key)
        if(isset($_GET[$key]) && $_GET[$key] == "x")
            return true;
    return false;
};

echo $either_abc_is_x() ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

Using a an array filter with a conditional:

```
$get_abc_keys_equal_to_x = array_filter(['a','b','c'], function($v) {
  return isset($_GET[$v]) && $_GET[$v] == 'x';
});

echo $get_abc_keys_equal_to_x ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

Array gymnastics:

```
$either_abc_is_x = isset($_GET) && in_array('x', array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip(['a','b','c'])));

echo $either_abc_is_x ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```